# Overwriting with blank cells

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I'm having an issue with a macro. VBA code below. Was originally designed so the user enters all data each day and runs macro once to copy to another sheet. Now user is entering a bit of data, running the macro and coming back later to enter more. Every time the macro is run the previous data for that day gets overwritten with the blank cells and small amount of new data.

```
Sub copyHME()

    Dim inputSheet As Worksheet
    Set inputSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Entry - HME")
    
    Dim copyRange As Range
    Set copyRange = inputSheet.Range("H4:H200")
    
    Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
    Set outputSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SMU - HME")
        
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Set searchRange = outputSheet.Range("3:3")
       
    Dim dateCell As Range
    Set dateCell = inputSheet.Range("H2")
    
    Dim targetDate As Variant
    targetDate = DateTime.DateValue(dateCell.Value)
    
    'Unprotect the sheet "SMU - HME"
    Sheets("SMU - HME").Unprotect Password:="XXX"
    
    'Clears all filters - if filters are left before next action data gets copied into the incorrect cells
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    End If
    
    Dim currentCell As Range
    For Each currentCell In searchRange
        If IsDate(currentCell.Value) Then
            If DateTime.DateValue(currentCell.Value) = targetDate Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    
    If Not currentCell Is Nothing Then
        inputSheet.Activate
        copyRange.Select
        Selection.Copy
        outputSheet.Activate
        currentCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Call Selection.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

    Call MacroLock
         
    Sheets("Data Entry - HME").Select
    MsgBox "Data entry completed"
    
End Sub
```

There has to be something simple I'm missing.

Comment: It depends on what's the content in H4:H200 on inputsheet. `the previous data for that day gets overwritten` if users remove contents from cells before running the code again.

Answer (score 0):

- Revised code copies only the incremental data to the destination sheet.

For example,

- users input data in H4:H10, run the code to copy data to destination sheet
- then input data in H11:H20, running the code again will only copy H11:H20, regardless of whether there is a change in H4:H10 or not.
- *Note:* Users have to clear the data in the destination sheet if they want to copy over all data again.

```vb
    If Not currentCell Is Nothing Then
        Set currentCell = outputSheet.Cells(outputSheet.Rows.Count, currentCell.Column).End(xlUp)
        If currentCell.Row < 201 Then
            With inputSheet.Range("H" & currentCell.Row + 1 & ":H200")
                currentCell.Resize(.Cells.Count, 1).Value = .Value
            End With
        End If
    End If
```